# how to iterate an object based on key and remove the rest items

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this json file and i have tried to filter the data keep only the user:'11111', but its not working.

```
var data= [
  {
    id: {
      server: 'xxxxx',
      user: '123456',
      _serialized: '64566'
    },
    name: 'Doe',
    isCalled: false,
    isReceived: false,
    unreadCount: 1,
  },
  {
    
    id: {
      server: 'xxxxx',
      user: '123456',
      _serialized: '64566'
    },
    name: 'Doe',
    isCalled: false,
    isReceived: false,
    unreadCount: 1,

  },
  {
    
    id: {
      server: 'xxxxx',
      user: '123456',
      _serialized: '64566'
    },
    name: 'Doe',
    isCalled: false,
    isReceived: false,
    unreadCount: 1,

  }
]
```

i tried

```
 const seun = sex.map(({ id, ...rest }) => rest);
```

but did not work

**desired result:**

```
var data= [
  {
    
      user: '123456'
     
    },
   
  {
    
    
      user: '123456',
    
    },
   
  {
   
      user: '123456',
     
    },
   

  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.map( x => f(x) )`this will iterate over the elements of array, and return a new array whos elements are the `f(x)`

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": { "server": "xxxxx", "user": "123456", "_serialized": "64566" },
    "name": "Doe",
    "isCalled": false,
    "isReceived": false,
    "unreadCount": 1
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "server": "xxxxx",
      "user": "123456",
      "_serialized": "64566"
    },
    "name": "Doe",
    "isCalled": false,
    "isReceived": false,
    "unreadCount": 1
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "server": "xxxxx",
      "user": "123456",
      "_serialized": "64566"
    },
    "name": "Doe",
    "isCalled": false,
    "isReceived": false,
    "unreadCount": 1
  }
]

const newData = data.map(d => ({ "user": d.id.user }));

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = [{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1,},{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1,},{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1}]

const result = data.map(({ id: { user } }) => ({ user }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like magic

Answer (score 0):

`Array#map` (see @YosvelQuintero's answer) is the best method to use. Here I show that you may also use the `Array#reduce` method:

```js
const 
    data = [{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1,},{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1,},{id: {server: 'xxxxx',user: '123456',_serialized: '64566',},name: 'Doe',isCalled: false,isReceived: false,unreadCount: 1}],

    output = data.reduce(
        (acc, { id: { user } }) => [...acc,{ user }],[]
    );

console.log( output );
```